# Handling single and multiple values in C# methods effectively

Tags: c#, .net, methods

I have a method like:

```
AverageAndDoSomeMath (Point2)
```

and I wonder how to handle:

```
AverageAndDoSomeMath (Point2) // single
AverageAndDoSomeMath (Point2 collection) // multiple
```

using a single implementation preferably.

For collection, I plan to use the IEnumerable type so I can pass any kind of collection, but for a single value, I don't want to wrap and pass it as a collection, because the collection itself serves no purpose, other than to satisfy the type.

How to best handle it in the clearest, fastest, most efficient way?

EDIT: Maybe I should have chosen a better method name, but the method calculates the average of all the points, for 1 value it doesn't make sense, but think of it as that the value will be used to say calculate another value, but what's important is finding the average, so I can't call the 1st method.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know you said you didn't want to wrap it and pass it as a collection, but there are two ways you can do this with minimal hassle, so I'll post them in case you weren't aware of one.

You could use params on your method:

```
public void Average(params Point2[] points)
```

after which you can call it with any number of arguments, or with an array:

```
Average(P1);
Average(P2, P3, P4);
Average(); // this one becomes an empty array in the method

Point[] array = new Point[] { P1, P2, P3, P4 };
Average(array);
```

Or alternately, you can use short array syntax to wrap up your object:

```
Average({ P1 }); // this is legal C# for making an array with 1 element
```

**EDIT:**  After reading your note, I would suggest that a params array is the clearest way to do what you want.  The only real downside to it is that you can't pass in an `IEnumerable<Point2>` (or other collections like a `List<Point2>`) without first calling `ToArray()`, because it only takes actual arrays.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the last one. Btw the params is strictly for arrays, right? Not Lists, etc?

Comment: Never knew about the params keyword, that's great.

Comment: Yeah the params keyword is great, but man, it's really a shame it doesn't support other collections. It would be awesome for IEnumerables.

Answer (score 9):

Write two methods

- AverageAndDoSomeMath (Point2 point)
- AverageAndDoSomeMath (IEnumerable<Point2> points)

and make the 1st one call the 2nd one by wrapping it in a collection.

```
public decimal AverageAndDoSomeMath (Point2 point)
{
    return AverageAndSomeMath(new []{point});
}
```

I'm guessing that's what you already had in mind but thought it wasn't the correct solution, right?

**Edit:** Simplified the method (thanks to Freddy Rios)

Comment: Rather, it would have to work the other way around, where the first one calls the second one by wrapping it in a collection.

Comment: Yes, make the single method call the collection method.

Comment: Thanks. No I knew it was the "correct" solution, but I can't justify making a collection just to pass.

Comment: Joan, you might be over optimizing. I really suggest just go with this approach.

Comment: btw, if you are using IEnumerable, this method can just: return AverageAndSomeMath(new []{point});

Comment: It can actually be return AverageAndSomeMath({ point }), as in my answer -- but at this point, why have an overload at all?

Comment: Thanks I see your points, but I am not concerned about speed, but more like the inability to call a proper method. I guess I can use the wrapper like you said, but if you look at it, with the same implementation duplicated, this would work, just some adjustments.

Answer (score 1):

a single responsibility per method would say your method should only do one thing - calculate the arithmetic mean - and that's it.  No "AndDoSomeOtherMath".

And if you look at the [formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArithmeticMean.html) for the mean, you can certainly calculate something meaningful with just one point.  It's standard deviation that requires two or more.

FYI, you can calculate a mean and standard deviation on the fly without having to store all the values.  It's a lot easier on memory.  John D. Cook has a [great blog article](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/09/26/comparing-three-methods-of-computing-standard-deviation/) on how to do it for standard deviation.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that method was just an example. Couldn't think of a better name, but yeah I always use single operations per method.